# Using solve on conditional functions

Tags: equation-solving, code-review, conditional

I know that the code is pretty long, but most of it is just defintion. Do you see why the Solve gives me "his system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve" back?

```
p[A1] := 30
p[A2] := 30
p[B1] := 60
p[B2] := 60
p[A12] := 100
p[B12] := 70

a[l1] := 10
a[h1] := 40
b[l1] := 20
b[h1] := 50
a[l2] := 10
a[h2] := 40
b[l2] := 20
b[h2] := 50

(*all low*)
x = a[l1];
y = a[l2];
u = b[l1];
v = b[l2];

(*G[1,x_,y_] is probability of player a playing with 1 given 1 and 2 \
play with him*)
G[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[A12] - x - y >= p[A2] - y && p[A12] - x - y >= 0
G[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[A1] - x > p[A2] - y && p[A1] - x >= 0
G[1, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; p[A1] - x == p[A2] - y && p[A1] - x >= 0
G[1, x_, y_] := 0

(*A spielt mit 1 wenn nur 1*)
G[2, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[A1] - x >= 0
G[2, x_, y_] := 0

(*A spielt mit 2 wenn beide*)
G[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[A12] - x - y >= p[A1] - x && p[A12] - x - y >= 0
G[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[A2] - y > p[A1] - x && p[A2] - y >= 0
G[3, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; p[A2] - y == p[A1] - x && p[A2] - y >= 0
G[3, x_, y_] := 0

(*A spielt mit 2 wenn nur 2*)
G[4, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[A2] - y >= 0
G[4, x_, y_] := 0

(*B spielt mit 1 wenn beide*)
H[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[B12] - x - y >= p[B2] - y && p[B12] - x - y >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[B1] - x > p[B2] - y && p[B1] - x >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; p[B1] - x == p[B2] - y && p[B1] - x >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 0

(*B spielt mit 1 wenn nur 1*)
H[2, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[B1] - x >= 0
H[2, x_, y_] := 0

(*B spielt mit 2 wenn beide*)
H[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[B12] - x - y >= p[B1] - x && p[B12] - x - y >= 0
H[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[B2] - y > p[B1] - x && p[B2] - y >= 0
H[3, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; p[B2] - y == p[B1] - x && p[B2] - y >= 0
H[3, x_, y_] := 0

(*B spielt mit 2 wenn nur 2*)
H[4, x_, y_] := 1 /; p[B2] - y >= 0
H[4, x_, y_] := 0



(*Find Solution,l:=EV von 1 mit A,m:=1 mit B,n:=2 mit A,o:=2 mit B*)
(*P[q_,w,] is probability that 1 selects A given bids u,v,x,y*)
P[q_, w_] := 1 /; q > w
P[q_, w_] := 1/2 /; q == w
P[q_, w_] := 0 /; q < w
(*U[q_,w,] is probability that 1 selects B given bids u,v,x,y*)
U[q_, w_] := 1 /; w > q
U[q_, w_] := 1/2 /; w == q
U[q_, w_] := 0 /; w < q

(*S[q_,w,] is probability that 2 selects A given bids u,v,x,y*)
S[f_, g_] := 1 /; f > g
S[f_, g_] := 1/2 /; f == g
S[f_, g_] := 0 /; f < g

(*S[q_,w,] is probability that 2 selects B given bids u,v,x,y*)
T[f_, g_] := 1 /; g > f
T[f_, g_] := 1/2 /; g == f
T[f_, g_] := 0 /; g < f

eqn = {l == S[n, c]*G[1, x, y]*x + (1 - S[n, c])*G[2, x, y]*x, 
  m == T[n, c]*H[1, u, v]*u + (1 - T[n, c])*H[2, u, v]*u, 
  n == P[l, m]*G[3, x, y]*y + (1 - P[l, m])*G[4, x, y]*y, 
  c == U[l, m]*H[3, u, v]*v + (1 - U[l, m])*H[4, u, v]*v}

Solve[eqn, {l, m, n, c}]
```

Comment: Your functions are defined procedurally.

Comment: Try and redefine your functions using `Piecewise`, or `Boole`, rather than multiple conditional definitions. That may help. I'm sure that you also realize that Solve would have to generate quite a few conditions and explore very many branches of your solution space to provide a general solution. Perhaps, if you provide further assumptions on the variables, or try `Reduce`, you might have more luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be reasons you elected to write:

```
p[A1] := 30
```

rather than simply

```
pA1 = 30;
```

and I would think it would be legitimate. However I re-wrote your code using (what to me) seems a simpler format.

```
pA1 = 30; pA2 = 30;
pB1 = 60; pB2 = 60;
pA12 = 100; B12 = 70;

al1 = 10; ah1 = 40;
bl1 = 20; bh1 = 50;
al2 = 10; ah2 = 40;
bl2 = 20; bh2 = 50;

x = al1; y = al2;
u = bl1; v = bl2;

G[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; pA12 - x - y >= pA2 - y && pA12 - x - y >= 0
G[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; pA1 - x > pA2 - y && pA1 - x >= 0
G[1, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; pA1 - x == pA2 - y && pA1 - x >= 0
G[1, x_, y_] := 0

G[2, x_, y_] := 1 /; pA1 - x >= 0
G[2, x_, y_] := 0

G[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; pA12 - x - y >= pA1 - x && pA12 - x - y >= 0
G[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; pA2 - y > pA1 - x && pA2 - y >= 0
G[3, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; pA2 - y == pA1 - x && pA2 - y >= 0
G[3, x_, y_] := 0

G[4, x_, y_] := 1 /; pA2 - y >= 0
G[4, x_, y_] := 0

H[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; pB12 - x - y >= pB2 - y && pB12 - x - y >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; pB1 - x > pB2 - y && pB1 - x >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; pB1 - x == pB2 - y && pB1 - x >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 0

H[2, x_, y_] := 1 /; pB1 - x >= 0
H[2, x_, y_] := 0

H[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; pB12 - x - y >= pB1 - x && pB12 - x - y >= 0
H[3, x_, y_] := 1 /; pB2 - y > pB1 - x && pB2 - y >= 0
H[3, x_, y_] := 1/2 /; pB2 - y == pB1 - x && pB2 - y >= 0
H[3, x_, y_] := 0

H[4, x_, y_] := 1 /; pB2 - y >= 0
H[4, x_, y_] := 0
```

Note that the way it was written the `P`, `U`, `S` and `T` functions are identical (again, you may have something different in mind). So I only wrote one. In order to help `Solve` I stipulated that the input arguments should be numeric.

```
P[q_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ] := 1 /; q > w
P[q_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ] := 1/2 /; q == w
P[q_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ] := 0 /; q < w
```

The equation is unchanged except that only `P` was used

```
eqn = {
  l == P[n, c]*G[1, x, y]*x + (1 - P[n, c])*G[2, x, y]*x, 
  m == P[n, c]*H[1, x, v]*u + (1 - P[n, c])*H[2, u, v]*u, 
  n == P[l, m]*G[3, x, y]*y + (1 - P[l, m])*G[4, x, y]*y, 
  c == P[l, m]*H[3, u, v]*v + (1 - P[l, m])*H[4, u, v]*v
  }
```

Now `Solve` yields a result

```
Solve[eqn, {l, m, n, c}]

{{l -> 10, m -> 20, n -> 10, c -> 20}}
```

I don't know whether it is the `_?NumberQ` or the removal of the nested `SetDelayed` (i.e, `:=`) that caused it to work. Perhaps you can track that down.

Good luck!

Comment: La Ligne: Zhank you very much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear[p, a, b, G, H, P, U, S, T]

p[A1] = 30; p[A2] = 30;
p[B1] = 60; p[B2] = 60;
p[A12] = 100; p[B12] = 70;

a[l1] = 10; a[h1] = 40;
b[l1] = 20; b[h1] = 50;
a[l2] = 10; a[h2] = 40;
b[l2] = 20; b[h2] = 50;

(*all low*)
x = a[l1]; y = a[l2];
u = b[l1]; v = b[l2];
```

Rather than adding conditions to mutiple definitions, use [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
(*G[1,x_,y_] is probability of player a playing with 1 given 1 and 2 play \
with him*)
G[1, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{
    {1, p[A12] - x - y >= p[A2] - y && p[A12] - x - y >= 0 || 
      p[A1] - x > p[A2] - y && p[A1] - x >= 0},
    {1/2, p[A1] - x == p[A2] - y && p[A1] - x >= 0}}];

(*A spielt mit 1 wenn nur 1*)
G[2, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, p[A1] - x >= 0}}];

(*A spielt mit 2 wenn beide*)
G[3, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{
    {1, p[A12] - x - y >= p[A1] - x && p[A12] - x - y >= 0 || 
      p[A2] - y > p[A1] - x && p[A2] - y >= 0},
    {1/2, p[A2] - y == p[A1] - x && p[A2] - y >= 0}}];

(*A spielt mit 2 wenn nur 2*)
G[4, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, p[A2] - y >= 0}}];

(*B spielt mit 1 wenn beide*)
H[1, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{
    {1, p[B12] - x - y >= p[B2] - y && p[B12] - x - y >= 0 ||

      p[B1] - x > p[B2] - y && p[B1] - x >= 0},
    {1/2, p[B1] - x == p[B2] - y && p[B1] - x >= 0}}];

(*B spielt mit 1 wenn nur 1*)
H[2, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, p[B1] - x >= 0}}];

(*B spielt mit 2 wenn beide*)
H[3, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{
    {1, p[B12] - x - y >= p[B1] - x && p[B12] - x - y >= 0 ||

      p[B2] - y > p[B1] - x && p[B2] - y >= 0},
    {1/2, p[B2] - y == p[B1] - x && p[B2] - y >= 0}}];

(*B spielt mit 2 wenn nur 2*)
H[4, x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, p[B2] - y >= 0}}];

(*Find Solution,l:=EV von 1 mit A,m:=1 mit B,n:=2 mit A,o:=2 mit B*)

(*P[q_,w,] is probability that 1 selects A given bids u,v,x,y*)

P[q_, w_] = Piecewise[{{1, q > w}, {1/2, q == w}}];

(*U[q_,w,] is probability that 1 selects B given bids u,v,x,y*)

U[q_, w_] = Piecewise[{{1, w > q}, {1/2, w == q}}];

(*S[q_,w,] is probability that 2 selects A given bids u,v,x,y*)

S[f_, g_] = Piecewise[{{1, f > g}, {1/2, g == f}}];

(*T[q_,w,] is probability that 2 selects B given bids u,v,x,y*)

T[f_, g_] = Piecewise[{{1, g > f}, {1/2, f == g}}];

eqn = {
   l == S[n, c]*G[1, x, y]*x + (1 - S[n, c])*G[2, x, y]*x,
   m == T[n, c]*H[1, u, v]*u + (1 - T[n, c])*H[2, u, v]*u,
   n == P[l, m]*G[3, x, y]*y + (1 - P[l, m])*G[4, x, y]*y,
   c == U[l, m]*H[3, u, v]*v + (1 - U[l, m])*H[4, u, v]*v} // PiecewiseExpand


(*  {l == 10, m == 20, n == 10, c == 20}  *)
```

Your equations are trivial

```
Solve[eqn, {l, m, n, c}] == {Rule @@@ eqn}

(*  True  *)
```